# mongodb linear combination of values for sorting

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm using mongodb (any version, I'd happily upgrade to make this work as I'm asking). I have a large collection (~50 million documents) with several numeric fields, e.g.:

```
{_id: 'doc1', a: 5, b: 2, c: 0},
{_id: 'doc2', a: 4, b: 9, c: 6},
{_id: 'doc3', a: 1, b: 7, c: 4},
{_id: 'doc4', a: 8, b: 1, c: 1},
...
```

I'd like to sort this collection by various linear combinations of `a`, `b`, and `c` (in reality there are something like 20 fields I'd like to combine). So for example I'd like to sort by `3*a + 4*b + 10*c`. The weights (`3`, `4` and `10` in my example) are something I'd like to experiment with rapidly.

I didn't see a simple way for indexes to support efficient sorting on linear combinations of fields. I know I can do this with the aggregation pipeline, but I think it will still require a collection scan for every new set of weights (?).

If I were implementing mongodb I can imagine that perhaps I could compute a index on the expression `3*a + 4*b + 10*c` efficiently by using indices on `a`, `b` and `c`, i.e. I wouldn't need to do a full collection scan to compute a new linearly weighted index. I'm not sure if that's true theoretically, and if it translates into anything I can do practically to solve this problem.

Any input is welcome!

Comment: Even if you could compute the "weighted" index from the other 3 it would still require to compute all values, then sort them. Out of curiosity, do you know any db engine that can do that?

Comment: @AlexBlex I don't know of any db engine. I was just thinking that right now in mongo I can add a new index, or use an aggregation pipeline, both of which require full collection scans. In theory mongo could avoid the collection scan by using the existing indices to compute a new index - so maybe there's some db out there which can do it? I couldn't really find anyone asking this question online so I figured I'd ask here for thoughts.

Comment: Well, it's very theoretical theory. Mongo doesn't compute indices from existing ones and very rarely uses more than 1 index per query. I must admit the question is quite unusual, what is a usecase? Are the weights constant or vary from query to query?

Comment: The weights will vary with each query. I’m exploring the data set and I’d like to find the ideal set of weights to use for sorting. So ideally I’d be able to see the results immediately given a new set of weights. Waiting for a collection scan seems to be my only choice at the moment speaking practically though.